# Twitter Bootstrap vs PrimeNg - Which one is suggested for UI development in Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, primeng

I have been using twitter bootstrap for quite a long time. It has made the UI development feel really comfortable. I have started off development in Angular 2 now and looked for the suitable CSS libraries. I found few of it like - `ngSemantic`, Angular2 Material, `ng-bootstrap` and `ng2-bootstrap`. Recently got to see primeNg and it looks interesting with the number of components it offers.

Now my question is : Is it recommended to go with `primeNg` for I feel the library can be commercialized in the long run.

Comment: PrimeNG team lead here, PrimeNG model will not change in future. The library will be free and open source, our business model is premium templates and support. Regarding bootstrap, in upcoming PrimeNG version next week, we'll add a brand new bootstrap theme so you can apply bootstrap styling to all PrimeNG components. PrimeNG does not tie you any css framework. There are themes for bootstrap, material and more.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 3):

A Recent project at work, I have used PrimeNG as the primary source for UI components, it is well composed and pretty much understandable. its source code is clear and for the most part, well organized, and it can be used easily with Angular. So I would like to suggest choose PrimeNG, Version has updated an average every 8 days.